# VBA: Get/Download Excel file from server and copy contents into a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, worksheet

For some reason the following Macro won't work:

```
Sub ExtractDataTest()


    Dim FilePath$, Row&, Column&, Address$


 'change constants & FilePath below to suit
     '***************************************
    Const FileName$ = "Dxo.xlsx"
    Const SheetName$ = "Open"
    Const NumRows& = 50
    Const NumColumns& = 20
    FilePath = ("http://enhanced1.sharepoint.hx.com/teams/")
     '***************************************


    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = Empty Then
        MsgBox "The file " & FileName & " was not found", , "File Doesn't Exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Row = 1 To NumRows
        For Column = 1 To NumColumns
            Address = Cells(Row, Column).Address
            Cells(Row, Column) = GetData(FilePath, FileName, SheetName, Address)
            Columns.AutoFit
        Next Column
    Next Row
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
End Sub




Private Function GetData(Path, File, Sheet, Address)
    Dim Data$
    Data = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & _
    Range(Address).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    GetData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Data)
End Function
```

I get a run-time error '52' on line ("Bad file name or number"):

```
If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = Empty Then
```

Funny enough it did work once. And when location is 'C:\' it works and I don't get an error. Weird stuff guys.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: its very inefficient to query data in a closed spreadsheet many times. Why not open, get all the data and paste onto the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file from a file system is entirely different from downloading it over HTTP.
The simplest agnostic way is to simply use `Workbooks.Open` which allows HTTP URIs;

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)
```

(You will need to remove `Dir()` as thats for file systems only)

Comment: Solved my problem. But now I have a new problem. The macro will download and open the file, but them it will say the file x was not found. Any idea why?